# My ad is not shown, ad failed to load : 3

Tags: android, admob, adsense

After the last update of my application the admob ad banner no longer appears, the admob code has not changed, the problem persists for five days, can anyone help me?

When I use the test banner id the test ad is displayed, but when I return my banner id the ad disappears again.

```
   MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus 
        initializationStatus) {

        }
    });
    adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ClienteActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=5173973406731336718, ad_event_id(_aeid)=5173973406731336795}]
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get ads on your app in test (debug) mode you need to include the below code to request test ads. It is good to test your app with test ads. Otherwise your admob account can be banned!

You need to obtain your device id for this. Run your app and check the console output. You will find this message in log.

> I/Ads: Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID") to
>   get test ads on this device.

Update your code as below.

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus 
        initializationStatus) {

        }
    });
    adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Read more about admob test ads [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)

Comment: I modified the code as you said, but the error still persists.

Comment: I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
D/FA: Logging event (FE): ad_query(_aq), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=am, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ListaAtendimentosActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=1818403420271118885, ad_event_id(_aeid)=1818403420271118908}]
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: Did you add the Device Id correctly? 

Also please check your admob id and ad unit id also.

Comment: The ids are correct, even when I use the available ids for example the banner appears, but when I return with my id (banner and app id) the ad does not appear

Comment: Is this the first time you put ads for mobile app using AdMob? For me my account was not approved (There were no ads for my ad unit ids) until I published the first version of the app on Google Play. So I published my unfinished app on Beta Track and get approval. But this is only works if this is your first time. Otherwise better to check with Google.

Comment: It was my first published application, but the ads worked until the last update. At the moment neither in the trial version are working.

Comment: I think you need to contact Google. Mention your issue and check whether your account is active.

Comment: Instead of Mobile Ads, use firebase ads and retry.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ads?hl=en-US

Comment: I tried to use firebase sdk, but got the same result, I contacted support to try a solution

Answer (score 0):

To load ads using the AdMob demo ad-units you need to use the correct demo ad-unit ID for your ad-format (e.g. Banner, Interstitial, etc) as listed here: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Add your device ID as test/debug ID with this code:

```
List<String> testDeviceIds = Arrays.asList(YOUR_DEVICE_ID_FOR_TEST);
RequestConfiguration configuration = new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(testDeviceIds).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

Also, if you are using app-ads.txt for your app, then you also have to include this line in your app-ads.txt file in order to load ads using the demo ad units (and wait for Google to crawl/update it):

```
google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0
```